# JQuery: Show mouseover of subelement when parent element is mouseovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

How can i mouseover an img element [ so that it's ALT attribute to be shown ] when i mouseover a parent element ?

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('div.dorp').mouseover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").mouseout();
    })
});
</script>
```

This code crashes my firefox webbrowser and i need to find a way to trigger img's alt attribute to be triggered when i mouseover the image's container which is considerably bigger than the image.

Comment: Can you just add the alt attribute to the container?  What about using a tooltip plugin?

Comment: You've got obvious typos - missing parens on `.mouseover();` and a `j` just sitting out in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: The title attribute shows on mouseover, not alt. Alt shows up when the image is missing.

Comment: Im using a tooltip plugin called `TipsyTooltip` and it displays facebook-like tooltips with the img's alt-attribute's content.
@Ivan : Eh,i wasnt paying attention,but i can create and use custom attributes for triggering the tooltip. Thanks!

Comment: @FlavorScape : along with lots of '3's,yeah :)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

`jQuery(this).find("img").mouseover();` ?

Mouseover is a method, not a property

And I'm assuming the stray `j` below that line is just a typo you made while writing the question, and not in your actual code.

Update:

Made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CmRT/)

What's actually happening is that the `mouseover` event fires both on the `div` and the `img`. The `mouseover` event on the `img` bubbles back up to the div, which causes another `mouseover` on the `img` and so on in an infinite loop. My browser gives the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'. This is probably what crashed your FF.

A solution for this (though ideally, I agree with the other posters, in that you should just use a tooltip plugin), is to add a `mouseover` event handler on the `img` too that stops propagation. However, this still doesn't solve your original need to get a tooltip on a child image.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CmRT/2/)

Comment: The code's syntax is correct,but im getting the error `jQuery(this) <---- missing formal parameter`